# Attempting to create a bot command that only continues if the exact word count is met. (Discord bot Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Attempting to create a bot command that only continues if the exact word count is met.

I am struggling to find ant sort of documentation on the information I need. Basically, I am trying to have the bot await a response and the response must have exactly 4 words, otherwise, it will go through the alternative response.

I thought this snippet below would get me somewhere, but I don't think I'm doing it correctly. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```js
if (collected.first().content.length == 4 ) {}
```

The actual code is below. Thank you for reading!

---

```js
bot.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message.content === '!host') {
        message.reply('Please send (Insert 4 word requirement here)');
        message.channel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id == message.author.id, {
            max: 1,
            time: 30000
        }).then(collected => {
            if (collected.first().content.length == 4) { //This is where I'm struggling. I want the bot to check if the collected message has exactly 4 words. If not, it should give the else if response.
                var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                    .setAuthor(message.author.username, message.author.avatarURL)
                    .setDescription(collected.first().content + '\n \n(Insert message here).')
                    .setTimestamp(new Date())
                    .setColor('0x7346EE');
                DChannel.send(embed); //This section is another part of my working bot. 
            } else if (collected.first().content.length != "4") {
                message.channel.send('Please try again in the correct format.');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track but are making a small mistake. You're checking the `.length` property on the collected message content, which is a string. Calling `.length` on it will give you the string length (thus the amount of characters it has) so only a 4 letter message would match your `if` statement.

By first splitting the message content on a space we can get the amount of words in the message. Take a look at the example code below and give it a try.

```js
.then(collected => {
  // Check if we got a message before moving on
  if (!collection.size) return;

  // Get the first collected message and split its contents on a space
  const messageWords = collection.first().content.split(' ');

  // Check if the array of words has a length of 4
  if (messageWords.length === 4) {
    var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setAuthor(message.author.username, message.author.avatarURL)
      .setDescription(collected.first().content + '\n \n(Insert message here).')
      .setTimestamp(new Date())
      .setColor('0x7346EE');
      
    DChannel.send(embed);
  } else {
    message.channel.send('Please try again in the correct format.');
  }
});
```

### Update based on comment

If you want to have each word on a new line there are two ways of doing so. You could use the [`.addField()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=addField) method for each word or once for the whole array.

If you want a new field for every word you can do the following after you've defined your embed and before you send it. It will add a new field for every word with:

```js
messageWords.forEach((word, index) => {
  embed.addField(`Word ${index}`, word);
});
```

If you only want to add one field with all the words separated by a newline, you can do the following (again after defining the embed and before sending it):

```js
embed.addField('Message words', messageWords.join('\n'));
```

Comment: Okay!! I got it, thanks so much.



I was curious if you know how to use this sort of thing as well to split each "word" and send it on it's own line in the embed? For example, if the bot collected the user saying "1 2 3 4", it would send in it's own lines? I think it would involve a field, but I'm unsure how to put the message content in it.

Comment: @Cressy I've updated the answer, give it a try and let me know how it goes